# How to add expanded drawer menu item to only specific item not all in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to create a drawer menu like below image display Flutter app

[image]

I have tried expanded drawer menu items in specific one item. Using a normal little use drawer menu so as not to add expanded..and using an expandable drawer menu so all item display expanded...but I want only 1 item expanded.

Comment: is it works @Boomika Aghara ?

Comment: @ஆனந்த் yes sir.

Comment: @ஆனந்த் i am new in flutter.ye flutter app me text overflow message ka kya solution hai?

Comment: @ஆனந்த் Flutter RenderFlex overflowed by 15 pixels on the bottom inside ..which solution for this error.

Comment: can u share ur code or send me anydesk id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  return Drawer(
          child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) buildExpansionTile(i),
            ],
          )),
        );


 Widget buildExpansionTile(int position) {
    if (position != 4) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text("Child Category $position"),
      );
    } else {
      return ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Parent Category 1"),
        leading: Icon(Icons.person), //add icon
        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60), //children padding
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Child Category 1"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Child Category 2"),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
}
```